# Is it possible to access the real and imaginary parts of a complex number with the [] operator in C++

Tags: c++, std, complex-numbers

I'm using the `<complex>` library in C++. Is it possible to access the real and complex parts of a complex number using the [] operator? I want to use `myComplexNum[0]` instead of `myComplexNum.real()` and `myComplexNum[1]` instead of `myComplexNum.imag()`.

I tried to do it using MingW 4.5.2, and I receive the error: `no match found for 'operator[]'`. I really need to use the [] operator for now, because otherwise I would have to change hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: Did you [search for documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/complex/?kw=complex)?

Comment: "I tried to do it using MingW and C99": to clarify, though, this is C++, not C, so if you tried it with C99 you probably had *a lot* of issues.

Comment: Trying to obfuscate your code?

Comment: You can convert the `std::complex<T>` to a `T (&)[2]`, this conversion is required to be safe [complex.numbers]/4. Therefore, you could use `template<class T> T(&)[2] obfuscate_complex(std::complex<T>& p) { return reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(p); }` and then `obfuscate_complex(myComplexNum)[1]` etc.

Comment: I'm wondering why you wrote "hundreds of lines of code" *assuming* you can index complex numbers before you noticed that it doesn't work. My advice is that you get started on fixing your code. (You can write your own `operator[]`, but I really don't think that's the best approach.)

Comment: Why must you use `operator[]`?

Comment: I didn't write the code. I have to modify a code where instead of using complex numbers, the developer used vectors. I understand that using the `operator[]` is not the best practice, and I will gradually move to the correct use of `<complex>`, but for now I really need to test complex without making a lot of modifications to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

You could derive from `std::complex<>` and inherit constructors and add an overridden `operator[]`, but I would advise against it.

Comment: Please don't. `std::complex` was not designed to be inherited from, and this will lead to issues in the long term. Do not use inheritance for code reuse

Comment: Overriding the `operator[]` was my last option. But I'm really trying to avoid it.

Comment: @JaimeIvanCervantes I would rather you use a `std::array<double, 2>` then write `std::complex<double> to_complex( std::array<double, 2> )` and `std::array<double,2> from_complex( std::complex<double> )` when you need a `std::complex` than do something like the above.  This lets you update "new" code to use `std::complex` while leaving the old code alone.

Answer (score 4):

As per [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) in C++11:

> For any object `z` of type `complex<T>`, `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[0]` is the real part of `z` and `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[1]` is the imaginary part of `z`.
>
> For any pointer to an element of an array of `complex<T>` named `p` and any valid array index `i`, `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i]` is the real part of the complex number `p[i]`, and `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i + 1]` is the imaginary part of the complex number `p[i]`

You can't do this with a `std::complex<T>` but if you *really* have to you can `reinterpret_cast` to a `T*` or `T(&)[2]` and use `operator[]` on that.

If possible, I would suggest creating an accessor function:

```
    template <class T>
    T & get(std::complex<T> & c, int index)
    {
        if(index == 0) return c.real();
        else return c.imag();
    }
```

and then use `get(c, 0)` and `get(c, 1)` where needed.

Comment: Using `get(c, 0)` and `get(c, 1)` still requires changing the code. As long as he's doing that, why not change it to use `c.real()` and `c.imag()`?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wrap std::complex in your complex class:

```
class Complex {
   public:
   explicit Complex(std::complex& value) : m_value(value) {}
   ...
   operator std::complex& () { return m_value; }
   operator const  std::complex& () const { return m_value; }
   ...
   private:
   std::complex m_value;
}
```

This will be necessary for getting the results of operations/functions involving std::complex as Complex.

Comment: `Complex(std::complex const& value) : m_value(value) {}` given that we are talking about 2 `double`s seems both better and sufficient.  And `Complex(Complex const&)=default;` and `Complex()=default;`

Comment: @Yakk The above is a sketch - sure that constructor, operators and functions are missing.