# How can I make my objects reinterpret-castable to arrays, like std::complex?

Tags: c++, c++11

I just learned this because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22919357), that the standard states for `std::complex` (26.4 [complex.numbers]):

> 4 If `z` is an lvalue expression of type *cv* `std::complex<T>` then:
>   — the expression `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)` shall be well-formed,
>   — `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[0]` shall designate the real part of `z`, and
>   — `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[1]` shall designate the imaginary part of `z`.
>   Moreover, if `a` is an expression of type *cv* `std::complex<T>*` and the expression `a[i]` is well-defined  for an integer expression `i`, then:
>   — `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i]` shall designate the real part of `a[i]`, and
>   — `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i + 1]` shall designate the imaginary part of `a[i]`.

This is something I really want to take advantage of *in a standards-conforming manner*. There are times when I have PODs, like mathematical vectors, which are composed of a single data type. Here are two example classes:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
struct Vector
{
    T v[N];
};

template <typename T>
struct Quaternion
{
    T r, i, j, k;
};
```

From what I understand, the implementation is allowed to add padding after the last member, as well as between members. Which means that `sizeof(Quaterntion<float>)` may not equal `sizeof(float[4])`, and `sizeof(Vector<double, 8>)` may not equal `sizeof(double[8])`. This means I typically have to add some `static_assert`s to my code to make sure that I can cast my `Vector<float, N>`/`Quaterntion<float>` to a `float*`, for example, and not worry about padding (for passing to C libraries or OpenGL buffers, for example).

Is there some method provided by the standard that would allow me to have the same guarantees for my little PODs, like `Vector` and `Quaternion`, as `std::complex` does? I'm aware of implementation-specific things, like `__attribute__((packed))`. I'm looking for for a non-implementation specific, standards conforming way of doing this. Since the standard requires support for this type of thing for implementations that provide `std::complex`, I'm wondering if there's also some standard way of applying this guarantee to my own classes.

Comment: [alignas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) is what you're looking for (I think). That, coupled with keeping your class standard layout, should do the trick.

Comment: @Praetorian: wouldn't using `alignas`/`alignof` just make sure the alignment is correct, and not actually ensure that no padding is added to the structure? Alignment shouldn't be the issue; it's padding that's the issue.

Comment: If `Vector` is standard layout, it is layout compatible with its first member (the array).  Padding afterward remains a problem: I do not know of a way to prevent it under the standard.

Comment: As @Yakk mentions, the address of a `Vector<T>` (assuming it's given a `T` that makes it standard-layout) should be convertible to the address of its first member, which is the `T` array.  That coupled with the fact that a pointer to the first element of an array is a pointer to the whole array, I believe would make `Vector<T>` (for appropriate `T`) satisfy the pointer conversion you want.  (I don't know why any compiler would add trailing padding to a single-member standard-layout struct, so even if it's not guaranteed, it's probably still portable.)

Comment: And you can `static_assert` that the size of the `Vector` is the size of the containing array, which makes the failure happen at compile time

Comment: @Yakk and @Adam: Yeah, that's what I currently do. I currently declare them like they are, and then just have a `static_assert` that makes sure no padding is added to them. While GCC/clang/VC++ don't seem to add any padding, the fact that the standard has this requirement for `std::complex` made me wonder if there's a way to extend this same requirement (in a standards conforming way) to my own classes. Right now my things are technically implementation dependent, but it would be neat if they could be implementation independent.

Comment: It occurs to me that you could try a `operator T(&)[N]() {return member;}` and then use `static_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast`.  I'm not certain it compiles, and it could have wierd side effects though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking the impossible.

Keep in mind that standard library implementors often rely on non-standard extensions or implementation-defined behavior. Indeed, in VC++'s complex header we find:

```
#pragma pack(push, _CRT_PACKING)

// implementation

#pragma pack(pop)
```

What you could do for your Quaternion is to place all the members inside an array, since the struct address can be reinterpret_cast to a pointer to the first member. But I guess that kind of defeats the purpose of the struct (direct member access by name).

It is not exactly what you ask for, but providing an

```
operator const T*() const // can be written in a portable manner
```

for your struct, will allow you to write

```
Quaternion<double> q = {};
const double * p = q;
```

at the cost of additional runtime/memory overhead, depending on how you implement the conversion operator.